# Why use link option when import file into eclipse project?

Tags: java, eclipse, version-control, filesystems

I know that there is the option to have **links** to source code under your `src` directory instead of having the source code files directly in your Eclipse project.

When is this case i.e. links for source code is best used?
I always found it more convenient to have the source code inside the Eclipse project

Answer (score 3):

I can think of two possible use cases for this.

- The first would be if you want to keep your source and IDE meta-data separate.  For example it may be that some developers use Eclipse and some IntelliJ.  In this case you would probably only want the source of the project to be stored in SCM, as otherwise, one set of developers are going to have to remove meta-data before importing the project.  If they just link to the source, they can maintain there own meta-data for there IDE.  Obviously this isn't an issue if everyone uses the same IDE.
- The second use case would be dependencies.  Say for example your working on two different projects `A` and `B` where `A` depends on `B`.  If your not using a dependency management tool or willing to build and import the Jar from `B` to A each time you modify it, you could link to the source in B instead.

I'm sure there are plenty of other use cases floating around.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what Kingamajick mentions, you could have a structure that causes overly long path names.

Windows can only handle so much (256 characters? in older versions), and a deep package structure easily breaks that limit.

So, having your classes in a shallow directory near the top allows you to have your workspaces deeper down, and still leaves some room to wiggle.

Comment: Is the `256` chars still a limit?I think it was in early `XP`

Answer (score 2):

Other scenarios; You have source code which is common for several OS:es, but the Eclipse projects are specific for each OS.

You can also create a form of linked resources that are relative to an environment variable. I've used that for situations where the version control system (ClearCase) adds user-specific catalognames.